# Python bokeh modify axis scale

Tags: python, axis, bokeh

How can I modify the `y-axis` scale at figures and at charts? I want something like this: `my_figure.y_range.end = my_figure.y_range.end * 1.3`

So I want a bit higher `y-axis`. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Figure` uses `DataRange1d` objects by default, which causes the range to automatically computed. But this happens on the browser, because it takes into account information like glyph extent that are *only* available  at render time. The reason that `my_figure.y_range.end * 1.3` does not work is because *the "automatic" value of `end` is not known yet*. It is only set automatically inside the browser. You can override the "automatic" behaviour of a `DataRange` by supplying `start` and `end`, but you have to give it an explicit, numeric value that you want, i.e.:

```
my_figure.y_range.end = 10
```

Alternatively, `DataRange1d` models have `range_padding` property that you can set, which controls the amount of "extra padding" added to the automatically computed bounds. It is described here:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.DataRange1d.range_padding

This might accomplish what you want in a different way, but note that it affects both start and end.

Finally, if you'd just like to completely control the range, without having auto ranging at all, you can do this when you create the figure:

```
p = figure(..., x_range=(10, 20))
```

This will create a fixed `Range1d` for the x-axis with `start=10` and `end=20`.

Comment: Thank you very much! The explicit way is my "friend": `my_figure.y_range.start = -1 - (df['my_attr'].max() - df['my_attr'].min()) / 20` and `my_figure.y_range.end = df['my_attr'].max() * 1.3 + 1`. `+/-1` is needed because I don't know whether `my_attr` is all zero or not.